# Django-Countries: wrong sorting in translated choices (but works in the admin)

Tags: django, django-views

I use [Django Countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/) like the following. In my view it seems to order the select items according to the english original values (e.g. `Deutschland` will be found under `G` (=Germany)) but in the admin the values are ordered according to the current language. This isn't done by [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391729/2704544) (I tried it by disabling JS). I have no idea how to fix this. Versions: Django 1.5.5, Django Countries 2.1.2

models.py

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
class MyModel(ModelSubClass):
    country = CountryField(_('country'), blank=True)
    #...

class MyForm(ModelSubForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel
        #...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['country'].required = True
    #...
```

views.py

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm
    # overriding `dispatch`, `get_initial`, `form_valid`, `get_context_data`, `get_success_url`
```

my_template.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{% trans 'Submit' %}</button>
</form>
{# ... #}
{% endblock content %}
```

I can provide more information if needed.

Another thing is that the ordering of countries with non-ASCII capitals is wrong in the admin. But I think this is [another issue](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/pull/44).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the choices with the original in `MyForm`'s `__init__`:

```
from django_countries import countries
class MyForm(ModelSubForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel
        #...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].choices = [self.fields['country'].choices[0]] + list(countries)
        #...
```

Use the first item of the choices to keep the empty value (`---------`).

As far as I understand it the issue is that the `choices` of a field in models.py are loaded at server start, i.e. once. In the form you can override it on a request basis. The sorting is done by `countries` (an instance of `Countries` in the same file).

I'm open for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Question has been asked similarly before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338838/django-countries-order-by-translated-name).

Answer was:

```
function sort(a, b) {               
        return (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) ? 1 : -1;
    };
$('#select_id option').sort(sort).appendTo('#select_id');
```

Comment: I've read this post before. I'm looking for the non-JS solution. Or did I miss something and it is sorted in the admin by JS, too?